# Can I create a Windows container with Windows 7 inside?

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-container

Is it possible to run Windows 7 in a container created on Windows Server 2016?

Or generally, which Windows versions are supported inside of Windows containers?

Comment: Here is documentation how to create base image. But I'm pretty sure since you are asking this question it'll be uphill battle to get this going from so many different points of view. https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/#create-a-simple-parent-image-using-scratch

Comment: AFAIK only Windows Server 2016 (and newer) is supported as "guest". Details can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility